# Get difference between 2 date_time in minutes

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp, php-carbon

Im trying to get the difference between 2 differente dates in minutes, but is not outputting correctly.

Ex:

```
$then = "2017-01-23 18:21:24";

//Convert it into a timestamp.
$then = strtotime($then);
//Get the current timestamp.
$now = time();

//Calculate the difference.
$difference = $now - $then;

//Convert seconds into minutes.
$minutes = floor($difference / 60);

echo $minutes;
```

Is outputting 611 minutes, and is wrong since from "2017-01-23 18:21:24" to "2017-01-24 12:36:24" it past much more than 611 minutes. Is my code incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set your default timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
```

Ofc change Europe/Copenhagen for the one that suits your needs.

Comment: You can see the different timezones here:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using or able to use PHP 5.3.x or later, you can use its DateTime object functionality:

```
$date_a = new DateTime('2010-10-20 08:10:00');
$date_b = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');

$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);

echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

You can play with the format in a variety of ways, and once you have dates in DateTime objects, you can take advantage of a lot of different functionality, for example comparison via normal operators. See the manual for more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i appreciante a lot, but it still doesnt resolve my issue regarding of what im trying to do, your just giving me another solution, and not aanswer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code it works perfectly So if have any doubt [see your result](https://eval.in/723011)

But you got wrong, so to ignore this set your timezone.